# How to perform decoding of one to many LSTM architecture

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

How to decode one to many LSTM architecture (https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/example-of-many-to-one-lstm/1728) in tensorflow? Can we use `tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode` of tensorflow?

For training I used `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`

```
cells = []
for i, each_filter in range(4):
    cell = LSTM cell / GRU cell
    cells.append(cell)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells, state_is_tuple=True)
states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=inputs.dtype)
```

how to decode using `cell` for one to many sequence problem **at test time**?

**My dataset is not about words, for example lets say i want to predict [4,1,2,3] given input 8**